# How do I reference a tag (such as <meta>) as a string in <p>?

Tags: html

I'm trying to reference meta and link as a string inside of the "p" tag. When I load the page it just shows nothing for where those are supposed to be. How do I fix this?

```
<p>Theoretically, I should have been able to do everything listed above by only using some "<link>" and "<meta>" tags.</p>
```

What it shows:

> Theoretically, I should have been able to do everything listed above by only using some "" and "" tags.

Comment: Replace < with &lt; and > with &gt;.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace < to `&lt;` and > to `&gt;`, because the browser is interpreting those tags as real tags, that's why it's not showing anything.

```
<p>Theoretically, I should have been able to do everything listed above by only using some "&lt;link&gt;" and "&lt;meta&gt;" tags.</p>
```

[image]

Comment: That worked! Thank you!